# Compiling C++ program on Fedora

Tags: c++, linux, fedora

I'm having problems compiling an open source C++ project on Fedora. When I download and run the ./configure I eventually end up with....

```
.
.
.
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
./configure: line 15513: AX_CFLAGS_WARN_ALL: command not found
./configure: line 15514: AX_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ALL: command not found
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking for bison... bison
./configure: line 15784: AX_PROG_GPERF: command not found
checking trace option enabled... no
checking for getrusage... yes
checking time profiling enabled... no
checking poll.h usability... yes
checking poll.h presence... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking forcing use of select... no
checking use pipes to communication between scheduler and dispatcher... no
./configure: line 16280: syntax error near unexpected token `1.39.0'
./configure: line 16280: `AX_BOOST_BASE(1.39.0)'
```

When I compiled the equivilant project in Windows I did need to install and update project  references to Boost. I can see that this is related to boost but not sure why I would get a syntax error.

A few other things to note, the original source code in configure and configure.ac had references to boost 1.3.5 with the same compile errors (obviously with 1.3.5 in the error msg).

I have recently installed boost 1.3.9 and updated the source. Also note that when I tried to

```
 yum install boost
```

it reports I have 1.3.7 installed and that is the latest version. I did also try 1.3.7 inside the source code but I get the same problem. I just don't get why I would get a syntax error!

this is the code inside configure and configre.ac that throws the error

```
#BOOST
AX_BOOST_BASE(1.39.0)
AX_BOOST_THREAD
```

Any thoughts on where to go next would be great.

TIA

G

Comment: Try placing the error within a "code" tag so we can see the error properly formatted.

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Comment: Might be worth asking for help on the forums/mailing list of the open source project. :P

Comment: Yeah I appreciate this is not a programming/code issue. I just figured this would be a good place to find people who might of done this before.

I'll also post on the Linux boards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your 'open source project' requires a later version of autoconf/aclocal 
than the version installed.

'AX_CFLAGS _WARN _ALL', ..., 'AX _BOOST _BASE', are all autoconf macros which 
would be correctly expanded if you had a newer version of autoconf.

Comment: thanks mate - I've moved on to automake issues but this got me past the original problem.

cheers

Answer (score -1):

I can think of several reasons for this to happen.
In first place, "Boost" is a very popular framework for C++ programming.

1. The project has a bug(a compile error)
2. You didn't install the dependencies right
3. The project isn't compatible with your distribution. The package on the repository may be outdated, so it is the most recent *for Fedora* but not the real most recent Boost package. Fedora users will be better fit to say if this is the case.
4. Some of your dependencies were corrupted
5. You didn't follow the instructions right